# Copy data for another table using Collections Types index-by table (associated with a table)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't know how to create a function with collections type. I am familiar with SQL, but I do not know that particular function. Here is what I tried:

```sql
Create or Replace Function COPY_EMPLOYEES_WITH_RT(
  Begin
    insert into jjj_employees ( select * from employees)
```

I want to create a function `COPY EMPLOYEES_WITH_RT` and copy data from the table `EMPLOYEES` to `jjj_EMPLOYEES` using Collections Types index-by table (associated with a table).

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your `EMPLOYEES` and `JJJ_EMPLOYEES` tables and the `CREATE TYPE` statements for the object you are going to use to store the employees data and the associative array (index-by table).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "(associated with a table)"? Are you talking about object-relational tables?

Comment: i need a function who copy data for another table with collections..

Comment: Collections (`CREATE TYPE <name> IS TABLE OF <type>`) or associative arrays (`CREATE TYPE <name> IS TABLE OF <type> INDEX BY <type>`)? They are quite different in usage as one is an SQL data type and the other is a PL/SQL data type.

Comment: associative arrays

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to improve your question, feel free to edit. For more guidance please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are using object-relational tables and particularly want to use PL/SQL associative arrays (index-by table types) then you can create your tables as:

```sql
CREATE TYPE employee_t IS OBJECT(
  id NUMBER(10,0),
  first_name VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE employees OF employee_t (
  id PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE jjj_employees OF employee_t (
  id PRIMARY KEY
);
```

With the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees
SELECT 1, 'One',   'Uno'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Two',   'Dos'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Three', 'Tres' FROM DUAL;
```

And the function as:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION COPY_EMPLOYEES_WITH_RT
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  TYPE employee_a IS TABLE OF employee_t INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  emps employee_a;
  i PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN ( SELECT VALUE(e) AS employee FROM employees e )
  LOOP
    emps( r.employee.id ) := r.employee;
  END LOOP;

  i := emps.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    INSERT INTO jjj_employees VALUES ( emps(i) );
    i := emps.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN 1;
END;
/
```

Then you can run the function using:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( COPY_EMPLOYEES_WITH_RT() );
END;
/
```

And the table is copied as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM jjj_employees;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME
> -: | :--------- | :--------
>  1 | One        | Uno      
>  2 | Two        | Dos      
>  3 | Three      | Tres
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=31935f31962d19435008c3e1005b3f28)*

---

## Update

Since you appear to want to use a collection and not an associative array:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COPY_EMPLOYEES_WITH_RT
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  --DECLARE type
  TYPE  EMP_RECORD IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE;
  l_emp  EMP_RECORD;

  -- DECLARE cursor
  CURSOR c_employees IS
    SELECT *
    FROM employees;

BEGIN
  OPEN c_employees;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_employees
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_emp LIMIT 1000;

    EXIT WHEN l_emp.COUNT = 0;

    -- Process contents of collection here.
    FORALL i IN 1 .. l_emp.COUNT
      INSERT INTO jjj_employees VALUES l_emp(i);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_employees;

  RETURN NULL;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN SQLERRM;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b06430f3dd9e469cb69090a5c23b2730)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COPY_EMPLOYEES_WITH_RT(O_ERROR_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR)
--DECLARE type
  TYPE  EMP_RECORD IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE;
  l_emp  EMP_RECORD;
 -- define cursor
  CURSOR c_employees IS
    SELECT *
    FROM employees;
    --
BEGIN
  --
  open c_employees;
  loop
    fetch c_employees
    bulk collect into l_emp limit 1000;
    exit when l_emp.count = 0;

    -- Process contents of collection here.
    Insert into jrf_employees values l_emp;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_employees;

   EXCEPTION
      --
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
        O_error_message :=  SQLERRM;
END;
/
```

it's like something like that, i just didn't know, what is wrong

Comment: That is not an associative array; its a collection (as there is no `INDEX BY` clause at the end of the type definition.

Comment: A slight terms clarification. An associative array IS a collection. What is refereed to here as collection is a nested table. A nested table IS a collection. There is also a varray which IS a collection.  See [Database PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00501)